# Is Azure Synapse Link a good way of loading the data in a Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse Analytics is the datawarehouse solution from Azure.

There are 3 ways to load the data into the warehouse:

1. COPY statement
2. PolyBase
3. Bulk insert

The fastest and most scalable way to load data is through the COPY statement or the PolyBase.

However now it is also possible to load the data through [Synapse Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synapse-link). Which allows near-real time data.

But I do not see any documentation referring to Synapse Links being used in a traditional Data Warehouse for analytics.

The use cases in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synapse-link-use-cases) are:

- Supply chain analytics, forecasting & reporting
- Real-time personalization
- Predictive maintenance, anomaly detection in IOT scenarios

Which are use cases that need real time data.

I do not need near real time data. Therefore I assume "Synapse Link" has some disadvantages for a traditional data warehouse solution.

Could someone please tell me their knowledge about using "Synapse Link" in a traditional analytics data warehouse ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With "Traditional datawarehouse solution" I assume you have ETL processes, that load/refresh your DWH say once a day.

The Synapse Link is a very convenient way to import Cosmos DB or Dataverse Data into a Data Lake connected to Synapse. The "real time" part of it shouldn't bother you, because you can always use batch jobs (dataflows) to load the data periodically from the lake into your datawarehouse.

With the Synapse Link you save time and development effort to bring the data properly from the Cosmos DB or Dataverse into your analytical environment. It works great for us.

Comment: Thank you Bernardo. So are using Synapse Link to load data in your DWH once per day ?
Found a post that does not include Synapse Link as a way to load the data in the DWH
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1013993/synapse-link-vs-data-factory-vs-polybase.html?childToView=1022459#comment-1022459

Comment: Synapse Link synchronizes the data seamlessly. It is permanently synchronized in your Data Lake. From the data lake, I move it into my Dedicated SQL Server once a day.

Comment: @Bernando I wonder if this approach is cost efficient compared to a simple COPY task. I can imagine a seamless sync with the database source can be more expensive than a one-update COPY activity from source to datalake.
For use cases in which you need the data almost real time it makes sense. You pay for it. But for a DWH that needs a daily update it might end up consuming too much resources and thus budget